# OpenCV uncalibrated camera rectification for 3D reconstruction

Tags: c++, opencv, 3d, camera-calibration, homography

I'm running OpenCV 2.4.2.

My project consists into a 3D face identification.

I'm trying to create a 3D model from a pairs of images taken by an **uncalibrated camera**.
My goal is to get some 3D features to use for the identification process.

I'm trying to calibrate and rectify the camera but I didn't get good results.
I did these steps:

- Extracted SURF features from the 2 images
- Found correspondences between the 2 images features
- Computed the Fundamental Matrix thanks to `findFundamentalMat`
- Used `stereoRectifyUncalibrated` to get the homography matrices
- Used `warpPerspective` with the first image and the first homography matrix to see the result.

I got a very bad result and I don't know what to do now...

Is it correct that algorithm? Any suggestion?

What kind of 3D features I could use to get a better face identification?

Here the calibration code:

```cpp
/// Conversione di 1 vettore di keypoints in 2 vettori di Point2f
vector<int> pointIndexesLeft;
vector<int> pointIndexesFront;

for (vector<DMatch>::iterator it= matches_FL.begin(); it!= matches_FL.end(); ++it) {
    // Estrazione degli indici
    pointIndexesLeft.push_back(it->queryIdx);
    pointIndexesFront.push_back(it->trainIdx);
}

// Convrsione dei keypoints in Point2f
vector<cv::Point2f> selPointsLeft, selPointsFront;
KeyPoint::convert(keypoints_left,selPointsLeft,pointIndexesLeft);
KeyPoint::convert(keypoints_front,selPointsFront,pointIndexesFront);

// Calcolo della matrice fondamentale
Mat F = findFundamentalMat(
                           Mat(selPointsFront), // points in first image
                           Mat(selPointsLeft), // points in second image
                           CV_FM_RANSAC);       // 8-point method


/// Rettifico la camera
Mat H1,H2;
stereoRectifyUncalibrated(selPointsFront, selPointsLeft, F, img_front.size(), H1, H2,3);

Mat out_right= Mat::zeros(img_front.rows, img_front.cols, img_front.depth());
Mat out_left= Mat::zeros(img_left.rows, img_left.cols, img_front.depth());

warpPerspective(img_front,out_right, H1, img_front.size(), INTER_LINEAR | WARP_INVERSE_MAP, BORDER_TRANSPARENT);
warpPerspective(img_left,out_left, H2, img_left.size(), INTER_LINEAR | WARP_INVERSE_MAP, BORDER_TRANSPARENT);

imshow("out_right", out_right);
imshow("out_left", out_left);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all first detection/identification has nothing to do with 3D reconstruction. Supposing that you want to do indeed a 3D reconstruction of an object from one uncalibrated camera, there you have usually two options:

1) you first calibrate the camera using a calibration pattern (usually a chess like pattern); see camera_calibration.cpp example.

2) you can both calibrate and do 3D reconstruction in the same time, and the simplest process goes like this: first extract salient points (features) using ANY feature detection algorithm (each has advantages and disadvantages, but with any of then you should get working results), extract descriptors for the found features, match the descriptors of two well-conditioned photos, find the fundamental matrix F, extract the two projections matrices (3x4 matrix) from F, triangulate the matched features, and then proceed recursively by resection: use the 3D points already computed and matched features in a new photo to compute its camera matrix (both intrinsic and extrinsic matrices), triangulate the new features brought by the new photo, and do a bundle adjustment of the whole reconstructed space (cameras and 3D points).

Good luck!

Comment: I have no way to calibrate the camera because they come from an online dataset, so I can't compute intrinsics and extrinsics matrices. I already have computed matches between 2 images. then i have computed F matrix and with "stereoRectifyUncalibrated"  H1 and H2 and then the disparity map.I computed "reprojectImageTo3D" from disparity map and an "imaginary" Q matrix (i don't know how to build this matrix so i used an identity matrix). What do you mean with Triangulate? could you be more specific please?I would like to use 3D features(if you have any idea to what feature use) for identification

Answer (score 0):

3D Reconconstruction without any intrinsic data is a pain, trust me. I'm doing the same thing with a modified flatbed scanner.

You can also check out the following post: [3d reconstruction from 2 images without info about the camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026567/3d-reconstruction-from-2-images-without-info-about-the-camera)

Answer (score 0):

Altough I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with this method for face images, I see the following problem with your approach.

Everything is fine until you find the homography matrices H1, H2 but after that:

```html
warpPerspective(img_front,out_right, H1, img_front.size(), INTER_LINEAR | WARP_INVERSE_MAP, BORDER_TRANSPARENT);
warpPerspective(img_left,out_left, H2, img_left.size(), INTER_LINEAR | WARP_INVERSE_MAP, BORDER_TRANSPARENT);
```

See the reference: [warpPerspective on opencv doc](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20warpPerspective(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20InputArray%20M,%20Size%20dsize,%20int%20flags,%20int%20borderMode,%20const%20Scalar&%20borderValue))

Should not have a WARP_INVERSE_MAP flag, since H1 is a forward homography and not a backward one. I get correct results by not using this flag and using Uncalibrated camera images. There is not trouble actually when you are using cameras which are uncalibrated as far as you are able to identify the fundamental matrix consistently over multiple iterations.

Try this and let us know if it worked for you.