# opencv detect real world coordinates

Tags: opencv, coordinates, stereoscopy

I have followed the stereo implementation from book "Learning OpenCV". I have the fundamental, essential, rotation, translation matrices and how do I calculate the real world position of an object that I have clicked on?

Comment: You can reconstruct 3D from stereoscopic 2D images using [triangulatePoints()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#triangulatepoints).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ReprojectTo3D`.

The reprojectImageto3D function requires the disparity map, an output array of the same size of the image & an array Q (disparity-to-depth map).

Q is calculated from stereoRectify function -> stereoRectify requires the intrinsic camera matrices, distortion coefficients & the relative rotation & translation vectors between the 2 cameras (R&T).

To calculate all these, use the stereoCalibrate function which outputs all these.
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html - this is the link to all the functions that i've mentioned.

So, the steps in order of coding are:

1> stereoCalibrate (use 2 views from same camera for now): get distortion coeffs, intrinsic matrices for both cameras and R & T. (Which you have already performed).

2> calculate the disparity and store the image - use the disparity calculation shown here ([3d reconstruction from 2 images without info about the camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026567/3d-reconstruction-from-2-images-without-info-about-the-camera)) to understand what kind of input is expected as the first & second argument to reprojectImageto3D.

3> use stereoRectify to get Q.

4> plug in all values into reprojectImage to3D to generate coords. Every entry in the output array _3dImage i.e. at each pixel we will have 3 values stored together: the x,y coordinate corresponding to the pixel and the z coordinate calculated from Q. This z coordinate is essentially what we want.

Once you compute the disparity map and get _3dImage using Q, each`(i, j)` of `_3dImage` has `(x, y, z)` values. I even ported it to PCL to view 3D Image and this is how it looks.

This is how Disparity Map looks like

[image]

and this is its corresponding 3D View using PCL

[image]