# Information needed for 3D reconstruction from x-ray images using OpenCV

Tags: node.js, opencv, image-processing

Anyone know a good starting point to check out, for 3D reconstruction from X-ray images/2D images using OpenCV. Im trying to do this project using nodejs and the js version of OpenCV. I basically trying to recreate the bone structure from a 2D X-ray image(multiple views are available). Open source codes(in python/c/c++)/algorithms/guides/anything is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you post example of data-set you are working upon

Comment: @nbsrujan Lets say we have an xray of the forearm taken in three different angles. My doubt is, how to achieve an accurate depth map out of this??

Comment: Yes, there are standard methods to achieve this. Some importand methods are given here  http://www.zib.de/projects/3d-reconstruction-anatomical-structures-2d-x-ray-images

Comment: @nbsrujan I have checked this out, but I cant seem to find an example or any algorithm that they used to make it possible.

Comment: can you please show some images (best would be 3 consecutive image layers where different kind of thicknesses can be seen)?

Comment: @micka Lets take an example where we have 2 different views of a forearm bone and wrist, and I need to 3D reconstruct this. (image here : [http://image.wikifoundry.com/image/1/BGeE_Na6CsS1DIAxpuffTw203771/GW720H503](http://image.wikifoundry.com/image/1/BGeE_Na6CsS1DIAxpuffTw203771/GW720H503))

Comment: no, it doesnt work that way. You would need slices of the target, not single unorganized scans.

Comment: @micka Sorry I gave the links to the wrong one, I edited the above link

Comment: You don't need slices of images. It is possible to generate images using various methods. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_reconstruction_from_multiple_images#3D_reconstruction_of_Medical_Images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you have the following:

- N image layers with each image dimension = width * height
- Interpretation from a color value to some "thickness value"

The general idea is:
Create a 3D map of dimension N * width * height with either floating point or byte values. Then just add your image layers to that map, giving you something like a huge 3D texture. Now you can define the tissue-thickness you are interested in, for example bones. Then search each cell in your 3D map where the values differ from "less than bone-thickness" to "bigger or equal to bone-thickness" (or just cells which have the exact thickness value stored) and mark those cells as "bones". Then you have some voxel grid of your bones :)

A better approach is to use something like `marching cubes` and interpolate between thickness changes.

Probably, if you google "marching cubes" and "x-ray" you'll find some more detailed information (and university lecture notes) about different ways to solve the approach. For example: http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/meshpapers/LorensenCline.pdf and from those papers you might find more tags to search for.

Comment: How many images would you need for marching cubes? Do you need many many slices?

Comment: @GokhanDilek probably depends on the precision/resolution you want to reach.

Comment: in fact if you know the size of a pixel and you want the same resolution in Z direction, you can compute the number of slices (or the distance between slices) you 'll need. See http://www.cs.carleton.edu/cs_comps/0405/shape/marching_cubes.html for an example

Comment: @Micka I am trying to reduce the number of images. If I had only 2 xray images to work with(1 is the front view of the object and the other is the side view of the object), what are my options to create a 3d reconstruction?

Comment: with alot of assumptions, maybe you could generate a single front-view slice from each x-axis pixel of your side-view image

Comment: Like these guys here: http://www.eos-imaging.com/sites/default/files/2016-02/EOS%20Solutions%20video%20%28R22-BRO-100-A-EN%29_0.mp4

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, to get a good 3D reconstruction image, you need to know some information about both camera (lens distortion, distance, calibration, etc)

There's a bunch of information online, here are some for good starting point

1. http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html#gsc.tab=0
   This is an example of creating disparity map. OpenCV has 3 stereo
   matching algorithm - Block Matching (stereoBM), GraphCut (stereoGC),
   and Semi Global Block Matching (stereoSGBM) - For more in-depth
   explanation, try http://scholar.google.com.
2. After you generate the disparity map, you can generate the point in
   3d space. However, as I said, you need some information from the
   camera. The code example in this question might help
   [3d reconstruction from 2 images without info about the camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026567/3d-reconstruction-from-2-images-without-info-about-the-camera)
3. Look for the sample from openCV sample folder it self
   https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stereo_match.cpp

   and the documentation
   http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html

Side Note:

I was using EmguCV, which is an openCV wrapper for C#, to create 3d reconstruction of human face. You might find this example useful, however, you need to find the corresponding method in openCV (they usually have the same name)
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Stereo_Imaging

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but the thing is, if im using normal images, I am able to do the above procedure and am able to create a point cloud, but when it comes to xrays, they are, in one way, depth maps(Im just not able to find the right threshold values to get a good disparity map). So would the normal method of finding a depth map work in this situation ??